# Constraints are not setting up properly, tried all ways

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, constraints

I am using Xcode 6.4 and want to give constraints to these 6 buttons (which are having background images) of pattern like in the screenshot.All are in a view and that view is also in a view. like:

UIView|
      |view|
           |view|
                |5 buttons

[image: this is the pattern(ignore the plus sign in all screenshots]

[image: after using all possible constraints, i am not able to resolve the issue]

Comment: image stretches automatically in all iPhone devices, i have gives constraints to all of the views

Comment: That depends of the way you set your constraints. How exactly you want them to fit in your screen? Considering it's an iOS application I don't suppose your view is squared, so you want them stay in that same proportion independently of the phone size?

Comment: well, thanks! but I resize them and set the constraints with respect to the size of iPhone 4s. And now it's working on all of the iPhone devices.

Comment: What is your problem exactly then? You already solved it?

Comment: solved it already!